# How to remove this type of shower handle?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I'm replacing the FRP board and I wanted to replace the handles while I'm at it. I'm not sure how to get the piece shown disconnected. The outer piece spins freely. Do I need to some how twist the inside part?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A photo looking head on might be helpful.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I snapped another photo, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pair of pliers to secure both pieces together and then turn counter-clockwise. This will then expose the valve behind the handle.

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of internally-engaged nut I usually try a sliplock or channel-lock plier. You can often insert the plier jaws and open them to lay against the lugs, then rotate to turn the nut. Might save you a buck-two-ninety-eight for a one-time job.